# Flatten Nested Json String Column Table into tabular format

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am currently trying to get a flatten a data in databricks table. Since some of the columns are deeply nested and is of 'String' type, i couldn't use explode function.

My current dataframe looks like this:

display(df)

| account | applied | applylist | aracct | Internal Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"id":"1","name":"ABC","type":null} | 2500.00 | {"apply":[{"total":20.00,"applyDate":"2021-07-13T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":200.0},{"total":25.00,"applyDate":"2021-07-15T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":25.0}],"replaceAll":false} | {"internalId":"121","name":"CMS","type":null} | 101 |
| {"id":"2","name":"DEF","type":null} | 1500.00 | {"apply":[{"total":30.00,"applyDate":"2021-08-13T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":250.0},{"total":35.00,"applyDate":"2021-09-13T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":350.0}],"replaceAll":false} | {"internalId":"121","name":"BMS","type":null} | 102 |

My dataframe schema looks like this:

df.printSchema()

- |--account: string (nullable = true)
- |--applied: decimal(38,6) (nullable = true)
- |-- applylist: string (nullable = true)
- |-- aracct: string (nullable = true)

How can I flatten above table and store individual record on tabular format, not in the nested.

Expected Output:

| account.id | account.name | account.type | applied | applylist.apply.total | applylist.apply.applydate | applylist.apply.currency | applylist.apply.apply | applylist.apply.discamount | applylist.apply.line | applylist.apply.type | applylist.apply.amount | applylist.replaceAll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | null | 2500.00 | 20.00 | 2021-07-13T07:00:00Z | USA | true | null | 0 | Invoice | 200.0 | false |
| 2 | DEF | null | 1500.00 | 30.00 | 2021-08-13T07:00:00Z | USA | true | null | 0 | Invoice | 250.0 | false |

This is my **Scala code**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.sql("select * from ns_db_integration.transaction")

display(df.select($"applied" as "Applied", $"applylist", explode($"account"))
        .withColumn("Account.Id" ,$"col.id")
        .withColumn("Account.Name",$"col.name")
        .withColumn("Account.Type",$"col.type").drop($"col")
        .select($"*",$"applylist.*")
        .drop($"applylist")
        .select($"*",explode($"apply"))
        .drop($"apply")
        .withColumn("Total",$"col.total")
        .withColumn("ApplyDate",$"col.applyDate")
        .drop($"col")
       )
```

[Error in Scala Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFKOp.png)

Also tried **json_tuple** function in **Pyspark**. Which didn't work as i expected. All applylist column value becomes null.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import json_tuple,from_json,get_json_object, explode,col
    
    df.select(col("applied"),json_tuple(col("applylist"),"apply.total","apply.applyDate","apply.currency","apply.apply")) \
        .toDF("applied","applylist.apply.total","applylist.apply.applyDate","applylist.apply.currency","applylist.apply.apply") \
        .show(truncate=False)
```

[Output of Pyspark Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj5wj.png)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm expecting more of individual records in each column. Just edited in my post as well.

Comment: Could you include the code used to read the original file, as well as any attempts you've made with explode?

Comment: Please format your expected output in a structured manner. It is extremely hard to identify what exactly you're looking for!

Comment: @DKNY Is it more clear now?

Comment: @scr Is it better?

Comment: @DKNY Didn't work as expected, some challenges with data quality. If we add a column called internalId in our original dataframe. Can we flatten by referencing that id?

Comment: Depends upon use case. However, more the number of columns you add, more the complexity of your would get.

Comment: @DKNY Just Updated my question, where I added Internal Id field. In applylist column, apply is tuple. Would it be possible to flatten those tuple with primary id as Internal Id along with other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pyspark, see below logic -

**Input Data**

```
str1 = """account   applied applylist   aracct
{"id":"1","name":"ABC","type":null} 2500.00 {"apply":[{"total":20.00,"applyDate":"2021-07-13T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":200.0}],"replaceAll":false} {"internalId":"121","name":"CMS","type":null}
{"id":"2","name":"DEF","type":null} 1500.00 {"apply":[{"total":30.00,"applyDate":"2021-08-13T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":250.0}],"replaceAll":false} {"internalId":"121","name":"BMS","type":null}"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

pdf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str1), sep = '\t')
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|account                            |applied|applylist                                                                                                                                                              |aracct                                       |
+-----------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|{"id":"1","name":"ABC","type":null}|2500.0 |{"apply":[{"total":20.00,"applyDate":"2021-07-13T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":200.0}],"replaceAll":false}|{"internalId":"121","name":"CMS","type":null}|
|{"id":"2","name":"DEF","type":null}|1500.0 |{"apply":[{"total":30.00,"applyDate":"2021-08-13T07:00:00Z","currency":"USA","apply":true,"discAmt":null,"line":0,"type":"Invoice","amount":250.0}],"replaceAll":false}|{"internalId":"121","name":"BMS","type":null}|
+-----------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

**Required Output**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema_account = StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                             StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                             StructField("type", StringType(), True)
                            ])

df1 = (
  df.select(from_json(col("account"), schema_account).alias("account"),"applied",from_json(col("applylist"), MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
    .select("account.*","applied","entries.apply", "entries.replaceAll")
    .select("id", "name", "type", "applied" , from_json(col("apply"), ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))).alias("apply"), "replaceAll")
    .select("id", "name", "type", "applied" , explode("apply").alias("apply"), "replaceAll")
    .select("id", "name", col("type").alias("type1"), "applied" , explode("apply"), "replaceAll")
    .groupBy("id", "name", "type1", "applied", "replaceAll").pivot("key").agg(first("value"))
    .withColumnRenamed("id", "account.id")
    .withColumnRenamed("name", "account.name")
    .withColumnRenamed("type1", "account.type")
    .withColumnRenamed("total", "applylist.apply.total")
    .withColumnRenamed("applyDate", "applylist.apply.applyDate")
    .withColumnRenamed("currency", "applylist.apply.currency")
    .withColumnRenamed("apply", "applylist.apply.apply")
    .withColumnRenamed("discAmt", "applylist.apply.discAmt")
    .withColumnRenamed("line", "applylist.apply.line")
    .withColumnRenamed("type", "applylist.apply.type")
    .withColumnRenamed("amount", "applylist.apply.amount")
)

df1.select("`account.id`" ,"`account.name`" ,"`account.type`" ,"applied" ,"`applylist.apply.total`" ,"`applylist.apply.applyDate`" ,"`applylist.apply.currency`" ,"`applylist.apply.apply`" ,"`applylist.apply.discAmt`" ,"`applylist.apply.line`" ,"`applylist.apply.type`" ,"`applylist.apply.amount`" ,"`replaceAll`").show(truncate=False)

+----------+------------+------------+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
|account.id|account.name|account.type|applied|applylist.apply.total|applylist.apply.applyDate|applylist.apply.currency|applylist.apply.apply|applylist.apply.discAmt|applylist.apply.line|applylist.apply.type|applylist.apply.amount|replaceAll|
+----------+------------+------------+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
|1         |ABC         |null        |2500.0 |20.0                 |2021-07-13T07:00:00Z     |USA                     |true                 |null                   |0                   |Invoice             |200.0                 |false     |
|2         |DEF         |null        |1500.0 |30.0                 |2021-08-13T07:00:00Z     |USA                     |true                 |null                   |0                   |Invoice             |250.0                 |false     |
+----------+------------+------------+-------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer. Upvote too, if you like.